# Programatic way to retrieve the Ruby version specified in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for an efficient a programatic way to retrieve the Ruby version specified in a Rails app Gemfile.

```
# Gemfile
ruby '2.3.4'
```

Comment: `grep "^ruby " Gemfile`??

Comment: Parsing the `Gemfile` did occur to me, but it doesn't qualify as efficient. I am pretty sure the version is cached somewhere and I only need to retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Gem.ruby_version`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubygems/rubygems/Gem.ruby_version)

```
Gem.ruby_version.to_s
=> "2.2.5.319"
```